# Make Text Fade Out on Type

Tags: javascript, fadeout, textinput

this is for a personal art project. What I basically want to do is create a blank web page where a user can type in text (like a text-editor), but have the text fade out as they type.

By fade out, I don't want the user to have the ability to see the text they had just written. So, I don't want to just transition the font color to match the background color as the user can select the text again.

So far, I've made a textarea that on keyup will store the text input, which will show in a separate div. I've specified in Javascript that when the entered text has reached a certain length: the div will fade out, clear the text, and show up again to show the current text input. The problem is that according to the console, I can't clear the value of the div. Does this make sense?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anelec/k40p72xk/5/

HTML:

```
<textarea type='text' id='myinput'></textarea>
<div><span id="fade"></span></div>
```

Javascript:

```
    //on keyup store text input into a variable "text"
    $( "#myinput" ).keyup(function( event ) {       
    var text = $("#myinput").val();
    console.log("event working");
    console.log(text);

    //show values of "text" variable in id "fade"
    $("#fade").text(this.value);
    var fade = $("#myinput").val();

   //function to clear text value of id "fade"
   function cleartext(){
   document.getElementById("#fade").value="";  
   }

   //clear text value of id "fade" after 15 letters
   if (fade.length >=15) {
   $("#fade").fadeOut(200);
   cleartext();
   }

   //show the incoming text input somehow
   if (fade.length <=15) {
   $("#fade").fadeIn("fast");
   }
   });
```

Please let me know if there is a better way I can approach this.

Comment: the reason you're not able to clear the value of the div is because you're trying document.getElementById("#fade").value="" and there is no element by the name of #fade. you're trying to mix jquery with normal javascript. try $("#fade").text(""); instead.

Comment: So how did it go for you?? You never returned to let us know, so I'm assuming that neither of our answers is what you were looking for? Let us know, and we won't hesitate to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
// Keep track of how many sets of 15 chars there are
var accum = 0;

// If the length is divisible by 15
if (text.length % 15 == 0) {
    $("#fade").fadeOut(200, function() {
        accum ++; 
        // $(this) refers to $("#fade")
        $(this).val(''); // set the value to an empty string
    });
} else {
    $("#fade").fadeIn('fast');
}

// Use the substring method to get every 15 characters to display in #fade
var start = accum * 15,
    end   = (accum + 1) * 15,
    next  = text.substring(start, end);

$("#fade").text(next);
```

Comment: Hmm, I added this, but it seems like it's only making the text blink?

Comment: At the bottom, remove the `start` and `end` variables, then change `next` to this: `var next  = text.substring(fade.length - 15);`  That'll make it work as you expect. I've updated it on my answer, but if you like Alex's answer best, give him the credit for it.

Comment: Hey! Sorry, I've been really busy the last few days. Thanks so much for following up, I can't believe all the help I've gotten! I really appreciate it. Both answers from you and Alex Cassedy are getting closer to what I want. I guess I should really clarify how I visualize the system to work: Imagine a blank white page with a blinking cursor where a user can type at any point, see what they're typing and after 2 seconds, their type fades. The cursor however, leaves off at the position where they last type and continues to blink.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this should work. You'll want to use the innerHTML instead of value.

Try changing:

```
   function cleartext(){
   document.getElementById("#fade").value="";  
   }
```

to this:

```
   function cleartext(){
   document.getElementById("#fade").innerHTML="";  
   }
```

You use `value` for input fields, and `innerHTML` for non-input fields.

---

Option 1:

```
$( "#myinput" ).keyup(function( event ) {       

        var text = $("#myinput").val();
        console.log("event working");
        console.log(text);

        $("#fade").text(this.value);
        var fade = $("#myinput").val();


 function cleartext(){
      document.getElementById("fade").innerHTML="";  

      // you use value this time because it's input field
      document.getElementById("myinput").value = "";
 }


   if (fade.length >=15) {
       $("#fade").fadeOut(200);
       cleartext();
   }


  if (fade.length <=15) {
          $("#fade").fadeIn("slow");
  }



});
```

---

Option 2:
THIS EXAMPLE IS FROM **ALEX CASSEDY** - IF ITS THE BETTER ANSWER, GIVE HIM CREDIT AND NOT MINE, I SIMPLY FIXED ONE THING ON IT SO IT WORKS.

```
$( "#myinput" ).keyup(function( event ) {       

        var text = $("#myinput").val();
        console.log("event working");
        console.log(text);

        $("#fade").text(this.value);
        var fade = $("#myinput").val();    

    // Keep track of how many sets of 15 chars there are
    var accum = 0;

    // If the length is divisible by 15
    if (text.length % 15 == 0) {
        $("#fade").fadeOut(200, function() {
            accum ++; 
            // $(this) refers to $("#fade")
            $(this).val(''); // set the value to an empty string
        });
    } else {
        $("#fade").fadeIn('fast');

    }

    // Use the substring method to get every 15 characters to display in #fade
    var next  = text.substring(fade.length - 15);

    $("#fade").text(next);

});
```

Comment: This helped a lot! The value clears, but now how do I get the incoming text to appear again?

Comment: Sorry about the delay buddy. I'm sitting at work, and didn't have a chance to get back to you quickly. Let me know if this is what you was looking to accomplish. If not, we'll get it sorted out for ya, but just clarify how you wish for it to operate. This example is based solely on what you typed in your OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I've gotten:

Javascript:

```
 $( "#myinput" ).keyup(function( event ) {       
var text = $("#myinput").val();
console.log("event working");
console.log(text);

//show values of "text" variable in id "fade"
$("#fade").text(this.value);
var fade = $("#myinput").val();


 if (text.length >=5) {
    $("#fade").fadeTo(600,0);
       $(this).val("");
    $("#fade").fadeTo(20,1);
}

});
```